# How to preload Linux on a laptop

Tags: linux

I want to erase a laptops hard drive and preload it for someone else. How could I do that? Is it even possible?

Comment: It's called "installing"...

Comment: I'm trying to do it for someone else and I won't be there when they install it. Very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention any specific distro, but I think OEM installation  is what you are looking for. It lets you install system in the way that end user can set username, password and other customization when first time machine is booted after installation.

Heres's Ubuntus documentation of the subject https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview

Here's also good explation of the subject http://segfault.linuxmint.com/2013/05/oem-isos-explained/